# Do I need to use IIFE with ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, iife

In the airbnb style guide it states that IIFE are mostly never needed.

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/README.md#functions

7.2 Wrap immediately invoked function expressions in parentheses. eslint: wrap-iife

Why? An immediately invoked function expression is a single unit - wrapping both it, and its invocation parens, in parens, cleanly expresses this. **Note that in a world with modules everywhere, you almost never need an IIFE.**

```
// immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)
(function () {
  console.log('Welcome to the Internet. Please follow me.');
}());
```

Can someone explain why this would be the case? I cannot find an explanation anywhere that says if I create a function at the top level in a module js script it would **not** be in the global namespace.

Comment: The whole point of modules is that they explicitly export things, the effect of that is also that top-level declarations are not global.

Comment: In my opinion, *any* namespace might be one you don't want to pollute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common use of an IIFE is to **create a scope** for variables to exist in so they don't become globals.

A module has its own scope, and a variable declared in the top level of a module is scoped to that module and not globally.

Comment: Thanks, seems I fundamentally misunderstood modules and my code was double scoped (and increasingly hard to fathom) as a result.